# Include Constable in moderation badges for elections

Tags: feature-request, badges, moderators, election

In moderator elections, according to [this candidate score query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/298418/candidate-score?UserIds=1530814%2C3622940%2C1252759%2C871050%2C572%2C1234256%2C1065190%2C492405%2C616460%2C224988%2C3366929%2C465378%2C229044%2C1380752%2C100297%2C1849664%2C189134%2C542517%2C2371861%2C2581872%2C109702%2C3001736%2C1069068%2C476%2C995926%2C1952862%2C2876565%2C379693%2C1603234), the Constable badge is not counted as a moderation badge.

Constable, being the badge one gets for being a pro-tem moderator for a beta site, would seem to be worth including - after all, the pro-tems for a site have proved they can moderate, so they should be credited in the election stats for it.

Comment: It would offset the Deputy and Marshal badges that they probably didn't have a chance to earn before being appointed.

Comment: Second it, though never been Pro-Tem.

Comment: This would be a useless statistic in pretty much all elections which are not the first election on the site, and would just make it impossible for users to have a perfect score. Past that, you can easily tell who the current protems are by the diamond next to their name. Does an extra point on a scale really achieve anything?

Comment: @animuson Give 'em 41 out of 40. No, in the grand scheme, this is probably irrelevant, but it would be good recognition for lower reputation moderators.

Comment: @animuson You could just count it without increasing the total score. Anyone with the Constable badge is very unlikely to have the flagging badges as moderators are ineligible for those.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The specific issue is that there are a bunch of moderation badges (raising flags etc) that pro tem mods cannot get. That artificially reduces our candidate score. For what it's worth I think the "incumbent advantage" and diamond next to our name already more than counteracts that so I don't believe that any change is really needed.

If a change was made then perhaps anyone with either of the badges for spending a year as a moderator should just count as having a max score in the moderation badges part of the scoring?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether it matters for two reasons:

- In the first election, moderators still have the Pro Tem diamond. In the other elections, they will probably make it clear in their story they write.
- I don't really think that one point in the score will matter in a decision between two candidates. At least for me, I tend to look to all serious candidates (i.e. a decent amount of rep and a decent amount of edits, flags, reviews), and then read their story.